# What is the name of this headland?

Tags: identify-this, lock-screens

I found this headland scenery on the login screen of Windows 10:

[image]

What's the name of this headland?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The natural arch is called [Porte d'Aval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Porte_d%27Aval_(Vue_depuis_la_Manneporte).jpg) in [Étretat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tretat), France ([map](https://goo.gl/maps/kxbEhjWXtic1fTkP6)). The [Aiguille d'Étretat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_d%27%C3%89tretat) can be seen behind the arch.